# Android app and online pdf + GMC service

Tags: android, pdf, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I must to implement an android app that contain a section "special offer", so this offer is illustrated in a pdf file that is on a web site and every 7/15 days it must be updated. So how I can implement this section? How I can open a pdf that isn't on smartphone/tablet? I read something about GCM service but it is only a change to advise that there is new offer. Sorry for my English...

Answer (score 1):

You can upload files to Google Drive or Box. (I prefer box,  because it's more mobile friendly) and open it frown webview or ChromeCustomTabs ( Chromecustomtabs is more stable and  fast but it want minimum Api 16)

This is official page of ChromeCustomTabs: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs
You can found how to use on Google.

Comment: Ok thank you, and what happen when I click on a file on custom tab? Offre me a choice to open the file?

Comment: @VincenzoSannino if yok Upload yor file to box there is a download button below you can easly downloads files. And preview files. Here a sample link of a mobile version of pdf file: https://m.box.com/shared_item/https%3A%2F%2Fapp.box.com%2Fs%2Fb2futy2xympro0njk9ph4nmb29d5zcii